# SQLiteDatabase INSERT-statement creates unnecessary zeros

Tags: android, sqlite, insert

I have created a database for my app with 5 columns. Each column only consists of integers.

At first, the table is empty. Now, if I add the values {1, 2, 3} to the first column (column1), I would like it too look like this:

http://pastebin.com/ZiUfDVEV

But in reality, it looks like this:

http://pastebin.com/zff926Zh

That is, it has inserted unwanted zeros at places to which I didn't add new values.

I have tried two different ways of inserting values into the database.

### First way:

```
DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
int[] sdTest = new int[] {1,2,3};
storeIDs(db, sdTest);

public void storeIDs(DBAdapter db, int[] ids)
{
    db.open();
    long id;
    for(int i=0; i<ids.length; i++)
    {
        id = db.insertIDs(ids[i]);          
    }        
    db.close();
}
```

And this method from the DBAdapter class:

```
public long insertIDs(int sd)
{
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(SD, sd);
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}
```

(where `SD` is the column name of the first column.)

### Second way:

```
DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
int[] sdTest2 = new int[] {1,2,3};
storeIDsExe(db, sdTest2);

public void storeIDsExe(DBAdapter db, int[] ids)
{
    db.open();
    for(int i=0; i<ids.length; i++)
    {
        db.insertIDsExe(ids[i]);            
    }        
    db.close();     
}
```

And this method from the DBAdapter class:

```
public void insertIDsExe(int sd)
{
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO "
            + DATABASE_TABLE
            + " (column1)"
            + " VALUES ("+sd+");");
}
```

Both ways give the same result: unwanted zeros.

How to get rid of them?

**edit:**

The table is created like so:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
    + DATABASE_TABLE
    + " (column1 int, column2 int, column3 int, column4 int, column5 int);";
```

Comment: How did you define your columns? Is there a default value 0 somewhere?

Comment: @Vache: Check the edit above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your table define default values for the columns? Columns should have attribute *DEFAULT NULL* :

**EDIT**

I have just tested it, in-memory sqlite db with Firefox SQLiteManager. It works.

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (column1 int NULL DEFAULT NULL, 
   column2 int NULL DEFAULT NULL, 
   column3 int NULL DEFAULT NULL, 
   column4 int NULL DEFAULT NULL, 
   column5 int NULL DEFAULT NULL);
```

and then

```sql
INSERT INTO test(column1) VALUES (4);
```

Comment: See my edit in the original post (at the bottom). I tried to add "DEFAULT NULL", but that has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a prepared statement instead of using a raw SQL query? Try using [`SQLiteDatabase.insert(String, String, ContentValues)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String%2C%20java.lang.String%2C%20android.content.ContentValues)).

Answer (score 0):

You can't get rid of them. If you want to use a database, then you are using tables with columns where every row of the table has the same TYPE of data in a particular column. If a column is an integer and you don't specify a value then it will have the value 0.

If you don't want this, then write a text file with comma-separated values.

If a column must be either blank or a number, then you could use columns of type VARCHARS but then you will always need to check for a blank value before doing any calculations.

Comment: Actually, I don't need to do any calculations with the integers. After storing them, I need to extract each row to an integer array (but of course without the zeros). Do you think VARCHARS could work then?

Comment: No, if you insert a row, and you omit a value for an integer column, that column will usually end up with NULL, not zero.

Comment: The point is that there has to be SOMETHING in each column. If you use VARCHARS then you can put NULL or "" there and then write some extra code to recognize that and produce your variable length rows, but relational databases just don't do this kind of thing for you.

Comment: On insert, SQL databases will insert the user-supplied value; if the user doesn't supply a value, the dbms will insert either a) the default value defined in the CREATE TABLE statement, or b) NULL. Doesn't matter what data type; all the common ones behave that way. What SQL databases *don't* do is put a zero in a column when the user doesn't explicitly supply a zero.

Answer (score 0):

Are your 5 columns are nullable?
Do they have default value of 0?

**UPDATE**:
Try to create your table like this:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
    + DATABASE_TABLE
    + " (column1 int NULL, column2 int NULL, column3 int NULL, column4 int NULL, column5 int NULL);";
```

(Not sure it will work because I don't know SQLite syntax)

Or maybe:

```
public void insertIDsExe(int sd)
{
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO "
            + DATABASE_TABLE
            + " (column1,column2,column3,column4,column5)"
            + " VALUES ("+sd+", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);");
}
```

Comment: Not sure what their default value is (I'm new to databases), see my edit above. Don't know how I can make them be null.

Answer (score 0):

A sqlite dialog. (version 3.7.4)

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE DATABASE_TABLE
   ...> (column1 int, column2 int, column3 int, column4 int, column5 int);
sqlite> insert into database_table (column1) values (1);
sqlite> insert into database_table (column1) values (2);
sqlite> insert into database_table (column1) values (3);
sqlite> select * from database_table;
1||||
2||||
3||||
```

No zeroes.

```
sqlite> select * from database_table where column2 is null;
1||||
2||||
3||||
```

All those blanks are actually nulls. That suggests it's not a SQLite issue.

Comment: How do I execute the select-statement in Android? I thought of `db.execSQL`, but in the documentation it says that it can't be used with a SELECT statement.

Comment: check this out: http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40842/1954 - example of selecting

Comment: @szamil Thanks, I've actually already tried that approach, but I receive a cursor with which I use `getInt()` - don't know if this is why I get zeros? How could I do it instead?

Comment: Does this cursor have a method like `getValue()` or `getObject()` or similar that returns object, in C# I would say nullable?